# OpenText LiveLink - Retrieve content of a LiveReport from database query

Tags: sql, content-management-system

How to query DTree (DataID) for the content of a LiveReport (retrieve the live report's sql content)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get the actual output of the Report, as the Report needs to be run to generate the results, but you can return the SQL that it would use from the ExtendedData CLOB which contains a Livelink Assoc object, one of the properties in there is SQL, which contains the SQL - including Replacement variables such as %1 etc - so this may not actually give you usable SQL.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!

I now see that it's possible to fetch the sql query that is being used for a livereport from the ExtendedData column, that's exactly what i needed.